# Can an infix function have more than 2 parameters?

Tags: ocaml

I am a bit confused by `infix` function.

So if I define `let (++) x y = ...`, then `++` is an infix function. I can use it as follows:

1. `x ++ y`
2. `(++) x y`

Basically if I remove parentheses, I can put 1st parameter to its left, and 2nd to its right.

Then can I define 3 parameters, like `let (++) x y z = ...`?

If I do `let (++) x y z = x + y + z` in utop, it is ok and give me:

```
utop # let (++) x y z = x + y + z;;
val ( ++ ) : int -> int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

I can use `(++) 1 2 3` and answer is `6`.

But is `(++)` an infix function? If I want to purely use `++`, how should I put `x,y,z` around it?

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/infix-functions-69640312a535

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# (1 ++ 2) 3;;
- : int = 6
```

Although I'm not sure when you would actually want to do that...